# From which language has English borrowed the most words?

Tags: loanwords

From which language has English borrowed the most words?

Comment: Wikipedia has a [pie chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Origins_of_English_PieChart.svg) and an [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_language_influences_in_English) to go with it.

Comment: @RegDwight Ugh. 3D pie chart. Are they even allowed on Wikipedia? ;-)

Comment: @KonradRudolph: What's wrong with 3D pie charts?

Comment: @Martijn They are completely taboo for professional charts. The 3D effect does not add any useful information and in fact makes the information *harder* to read reliably from the graph. In fact, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pie_chart#3-D_pie_chart) contains that information. Note that there’s nothing wrong with adding effects for aesthetics *as long as* they don’t detract from readability.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Thanks, never knew that.  Good thing I hardly ever make professional charts, then... :-)

Comment: @Martijn: Pie charts [are evil in general](http://catbirdanalytics.wordpress.com/2010/03/02/why-pie-charts-are-evil/) [(1)](http://blogs.oracle.com/experience/2010/03/countdown_of_top_10_reasons_to_never_ever_use_a_pie_chart.html) [(2)](http://catbirdanalytics.wordpress.com/2010/03/02/why-pie-charts-are-evil/) but [3D pie charts are even worse](http://fury.com/2010/03/why-3d-pie-charts-are-bad/). They only should be used with max. 2–3 different elements [like in this example](http://boingboing.net/2006/11/02/hilarious-piechartvi.html).

Comment: Stupid question: Is German regarded a Germanic language in this context? Because it's missing on the pie chart.

Comment: Middle English?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I initially thought it was French, but actually it's a draw between French and Latin.  There have been many studies on this topic, which came up as you would expect, with different percentages, but the conclusion remains the same.

There is a paragraph about this topic in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_language#Word_origins), and another [dedicated Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_English_loanwords_by_country_or_language_of_origin) that lists English loanwords by country and language of origin.  One interesting conclusion in the first article is that if you consider only very common words, the Anglo-Saxon proportion is more important, which is a clear indication of English's Germanic substrate.

You know, if you had asked the question a couple of centuries ago, it would have been French alone.  The reason why Latin has caught up is because many scientific and medical terms are coined after Latin.  Remarkably, the second largest contribution of Latin is actually the result of the introduction of Christianity from the 7th Century onwards and the Roman occupation comes only in third place.

The French influence really began with the Norman invasion of 1066; but that was only a start, as it was followed by a continuous influx of French immigrants in England throughout the Middle Ages and even after.  Indeed, a few of the early Norman kings rarely set foot in their English kingdom and couldn't speak English.  Saxon English nearly became an underground language.  However, many of these immigrants came without women, and once they'd intermarried with the locals, after a few generations their descendants could not speak French any more.

All considered, this was only too fair because the Norman people were actually of Scandinavian origin and they had made French their language for the same reason: Norman armies had landed on French coasts with very few women.  The date of the establishment of the French Dukedom of Normandy is 911.  Compare this to 1066.  A mere 155 years had turned the North men into the Normans.

Other notable contributions to English are Celtic (see below), Old Norse (due to the Viking invasions), Greek, Dutch (with William and Mary and the Dutch wars) and a variety of other languages especially from the former colonies.

Language origin specialists theorise that the proportion of loanwords in a language is a function of both the length of exposure to and the social status of the borrowed language.  For this reason, there are comparatively very few Celtic words — *whiskey* being one of the most prominent ones.  One clue to this apparent oddity is the double meaning of *Wilisc* in Old English, the Saxon word for Celt (⇒ Welsh): it means both "foreigner" and "slave".

Comment: +1 for a thorough answer. Do you know what the usage numbers are for the various influences? That is, there may be more French- and Latin-derived words in English, but which influence has the highest stats based on frequency of use?

Comment: @Robusto. Thanks.  Yes, [this paragraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_language#Word_origins) quotes a study of English word origin distribution by ranges of frequency.  For instance you can see that 97% of the 100 most frequent English words are actually of Germanic stem.

Comment: Are we talking about *borrowed* words, or *derived* words? Because, in the latter case, the question becomes a bit difficult to answer, as French itself derives from Latin! (example: *et cetera*: borrowed from Latin, *magnification*: derived from the Latin word *magnus*)

Comment: +1 A good answer, though we need more information to interpret these Wikipedia numbers. 1. Were the percentages acquired by marking each word in a text by its origin and adding up the totals? That is how it should be done; but those percentages for the most common 100, 1000, etc. words seem to indicate otherwise. We don't need a percentage of dictionary entries. 2. On what corpus are these percentages based? Writing? Speech? Register? This makes a huge difference. 3. As @Nico says, it must to be made clear what a word is: does only its "main" root count? What about suffixes?

Comment: ... should perhaps the status of word count at the moment it was first used in English? That is, a Latin word borrowed by French counts as French if an Englishman considered it French at the moment he began using it. Then again, this would be difficult to establish, and the Englishman might have had no idea himself. An alternative could be counting syllables or morphemes. Then again, that would make it difficult to distinguish between Latin and French.

Comment: @nico, the question is about borrowing.  That makes more sense.  Otherwise, why stop at Latin ? If you go back to Proto Indo European, you probably hit the 99% mark.  As you might have gathered by now, I'm very fond of etymology and there is always an origin behind an origin ("origin" is probably not the right word in that context).  But in the context of English sources, most studies are about direct borrowing.

Comment: @Billare, thx for the editing.  I edited this answer several times but was still unhappy about it. Thx again (this first typo was so ugly !)

Comment: @Cerberus. Thx. The study quoted in the Wikipedia article is extracted of [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=sKqx8k8gYTkC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false).  Unfortunately the specific pages of this study are not available on line.  I have other paperback books at home about this topic - in which I do take a lot of interest. I might be able to find some electronic copy on line.

Comment: @Alain Pannetier No problem Alain; it was a pleasure.  The essence of the answer remains entirely yours. :)

Comment: @nico: And another problem with ignoring the derived/borrowed distinction is that a significantly large number of Latinate words are actually English creations — they use Latinate roots and suffixes, but do not exist at all in Latin/French.  It is not clear if the pie chart considers completely English-derived Latinate words to be Latin or Germanic (but probably Latin). For example, *acid* is a Latin/French borrowing, as well as the suffix *-ic*, but the word *acidic* was an English creation, not borrowed from Latin or French.

Comment: "We (English) don't just borrow words; on occasion, English has pursued other languages down alleyways to beat them unconscious and rifle their pockets for new vocabulary."   James Nicoll

Comment: As has been noted, the issue is really quite complex and in various cases it's not clear whether something is a "derivation" or "borrowing", or which language to count as "the" language that it was derived/borrowed from. If you look at the figures for the studies quoted, many of them vary so wildly that the only real conclusions you can come to is that (a) there's "lots" of Romance influence compared to other languages, and (b) the question is to imprecisely defined to begin with.

Comment: @Neil, as I said.  There have been many different studies on this subject and they came up with as many percentages.  As @Cerberus rightly points out there are many ways of calculating borrowings.  However most studies reach the same conclusion.  As a Frenchman, I wish French had been as welcoming to other languages as English has been throughout its history.

Comment: Clarification: Old French (fro) (its Norman dialect) came over in 1066, not (modern) French (fr).

Comment: @msh210.  I agree.  The [cited article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_language#Word_origins) consistently refers to "Langue d'Oil" and "Old Norman").

Comment: It's worth remembering that labels like "Old French", "Middle French", "Modern French", "language d'oc/d'oïl", are essentially labels made up 'a postiori'. People of the 1000s that we would nowadays think of as speaking "Old French" didn't give such a label to their language (most probably didn't even think of it as being "French" rather than "Latin" or just "language"), and there wasn't a magical point where speakers suddenly started saying "ooh my goodness we're loosing our case system, we'd better start calling our language 'Middle French'"....

Comment: There is no such thing as old/middle French, but rather many distinct dialects. Just over a hundred years ago, those speaking French in France were a minority albeit a significant minority.